# ASP.NET Radio Button Switch in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I have a radio button in ASP.NET

```
 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" Text="Yes" GroupName="rb" Checked="false" runat="server" />
```

I want to use bootstrap-switch that i got from [HERE](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/)

I simply want to have the "Switching" effect on my radio buttons, instead of the default circles offered by ASP.NET.

Here is what i did:
1) Added Radio Button on my aspx page. As shown above.
2) used the following script

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("input:radio").bootstrapSwitch();

          $("input:radio").on("click", function () {

                console.log("Clicked");
                $("input:radio").bootstrapSwitch('toggleState', true);
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Now the behaviour is as such that If I click on "OFF" option, it slides to "ON"... but if i click on "ON" option it doesn't move back to OFF.
Interestingly, If I click on the Text of radio Button which is "YES", it then toggles.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$("input:radio").bootstrapSwitch();`, it will work, you don't have to write separate code for handling `click` event. I have tried a [Similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/nccq13kn/).

```js
 $('input[type="radio"]').bootstrapSwitch();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <h3 class="h5">Example</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="radio2" checked data-radio-all-off="true" class="switch-radio2">
  <input type="radio" name="radio2" data-radio-all-off="true" class="switch-radio2">
  <input type="radio" name="radio2" data-radio-all-off="true" class="switch-radio2">
</div>
```

And if you look into your code, you are always setting `toggleState` to true in `$("input:radio").on("click".....` , where as you should first check if `$(this).attr("checked")` is true, then set it to true , else set `toggleState` to false.